# Asymmetric Grids

Tags: gui-construction, grid-layouts, alignment

Consider the following `Grid`

```
Grid[{
  {7, 11, 11, 5},
  {2, 3, 4, 5},
  {Button["Hello"], SpanFromLeft},
  {Button["Hello"], SpanFromLeft, Button["Hello"], SpanFromLeft}
  }, ItemSize -> {{1, 3, 7, 1}, Full}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Is it possible to freely align the button items so that I can centre two or more subdivisions of a row? That is, for 2 and 3 subdivisions, get the following alignment, while keeping the upper rows item sizes

[image]

Note: the button items are merely an example, but it is interesting to see how `SpanFromLeft` works with buttons.

I thought about individually setting the item sizes, positions or even playing around with dividers, but with no real results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, I found some potential approaches. One is to use `Row` and `SpanFromLeft`

```
bl = 182;
Grid[{
  {7, 11, 11, 5},
  {2, 3, 4, 5},
  {Row@{Button["Hello", ImageSize -> {bl/3, Full}], 
     Button["Hello", ImageSize -> {bl/3, Full}], 
     Button["Hello", ImageSize -> {bl/3, Full}]}, SpanFromLeft},
  {Row @{Button["Hello", ImageSize -> {bl/2, Full}], 
     Button["Hello", ImageSize -> {bl/2, Full}]}, SpanFromLeft}
  }, ItemSize -> {{1, 3, 7, 1}, Full}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

There are two problems with this approach: the dividers do not appear and `bl` is chosen by hand (automatic, depending on the grid's `ItemSize` would be ideal, though converting `ImageSize` and `ItemSize` units doesn't seem trivial).

Alternatively, one could think of grids within a grid

```
bl = 170;
Grid[{
  {Grid[{
     {7, 11, 11, 5},
     {2, 3, 4, 5}
     }, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {{1, 3, 7, 1}, Full}]},
  {Grid[{{Button["Hello", ImageSize -> {bl/3, Full}], 
      Button["Hello", ImageSize -> {bl/3, Full}], 
      Button["Hello", ImageSize -> {bl/3, Full}]}}, Frame -> All, 
    ItemSize -> 4.3]},
  {Grid[{{Button["Hello", ImageSize -> {bl/2, Full}], 
      Button["Hello", ImageSize -> {bl/2, Full}]}}, Frame -> All, 
    ItemSize -> 6.9]}
  }, ItemSize -> {Full, Full}, GridFrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

This gets me close, though `Frame` becomes a mess. Perhaps using the old `GridFrameMargins` function could help somehow, but I'm not seeing how. Again, the issue of setting an automatic `ItemSize` becomes relevant. Any further ideas or comments are appreciated.

Comment: Adding a `RowSpacings -> 0` to the outer `Grid` helps. But this is still *far* from ideal. We should really have something like TeX's hfill